# How do i apply In-app updates to the non play store apks?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-update

I want to add in app updates checking in my application android studio(java) and i dont have a play store application or i want to do this for github (say) how do i do that? if possible can u guys please provide with sample codes...

lets say i have a app in github then i released the apk i want the application to look wheather the application is upto date or not and notify the user wheather the app is up to date or not if not i want the user to update the app

Comment: Check the version, if it's newer, download it and ask the user to install it. Too much code to fit in here, but you get the overall idea.

Answer (score -1):

In this situation , you need to store your updated app version let's say `firebase remote config` you can use . So whenever user open your app , you should fetch latest version available to download from `firebase remote config` and compare with current . You can check code in this blog

https://medium.com/@sembozdemir/force-your-users-to-update-your-app-with-using-firebase-33f1e0bcec5a

Comment: Using firebase for what should be a simple web request sounds like a bad idea.  You pick up all sorts of syncing issues, to avoid writing a trivial endpoint.

Comment: Thank u soo much i was and still am a beginner so i will check that out after completing firebase room etc